# Why is this event declared with an anonymous delegate?

Tags: c#, events

I have seen people define their events like this:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent = delegate{};
```

Can somebody explain how this is different from defining it without it?  Is it to avoid checking for null when raising the event?

Comment: If i am not wrong, the correct term for this is "anonymous method" not "anonymous delegate".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got it - adding the empty delegate lets you avoid this:

```
public void DoSomething() { 
    if (MyEvent != null) // Unnecessary! 
        MyEvent(this, "foo"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This declaration ensures that `MyEvent` is never null, removing the tedious and error-prone task of having to check for null every time, at the cost of executing an extra empty delegate every time the event is fired.